# Description of reactjs reducer related terms

Tags: reactjs, redux-thunk

Please give a brief description of **middleware**,**thunk** & **redux-logger** used in reactjs..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In reactjs, middleware is a piece of code that bridges two or more parts of an application. Thunk is also a piece of software that is primarily used to delay a calculation until its result is needed, or to insert operations at the beginning or end of the other subroutine. Redux-logger, as the name suggests, it is simply a logger. It is used to spit out information about the previous and current state of an application that uses redux.
I hope this was brief.

Please refer to [this](https://redux.js.org/advanced/middleware), [this](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk) and [this](https://github.com/evgenyrodionov/redux-logger) to learn about these technologies in depth.